# Why can class objects call the toString method if the class does not provide an implementation for the method?

Tags: java, tostring

Could someone explain why any class object may call the toString method even if the class does not provide an implementation for the method.

What happens in this situation and what happens when a class does provide a toString method implementation?

Comment: Because every class implicitly extends Object, and toString is implemented in the Object class.

Comment: It's all about the magic of subclassing and polymorphism!

Comment: [Object javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html): "Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Every** Java class is a subclass of [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class.

Thus, by **inheritance**, all the operations available in **Object** class are available in every Java class. This includes toString() operation :).

Answer (score 3):

Every class in java extends from Object class, it's a singly rooted hierarchy, the Object class has a defined toString method so when you try to invoke it with your class object, it works!

Since the toString method gets inherited from the Object class to your class

Morevoer, you can override the toString method in any of your class, it's return type is String, so after overriding the method, if you call toString with your class's object then it will execute the toString method you wrote in that class of yours and not the one Object class supplies by default

Answer (score 1):

Basically, since every class extends `Object`, calling toString calls the `Object` implementation, *unless* the class provides it's own implementation. The default method returns a String containing some information about the class. Overriding it allows you to return anything you want.

See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()